# element wise multiplication tenserflow Error

Tags: python, networking, autoencoder

i made my autoencoder in this way

```
autoencoder = Sequential()
Atac=Atac.iloc[range(2),range(2)]
autoencoder.add(Dense(minFeature, activation='relu',name="encoder4",input_shape=(Atac.shape[1],),kernel_constraint=prova()))
autoencoder.add(Dense(Atac.shape[1], activation='relu',name="decoder4",kernel_constraint=prova()))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam( lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0), loss='mean_squared_error')
autoencoder.summary()

autoencoder_train = autoencoder.fit(Atac, Atac, batch_size=256, epochs=1,validation_data=(Atac, Atac))
```

and im using the following kernel_constraint function :

```
class prova(constraints.Constraint):
    def __call__(self, w):
        #return tf.math.multiply(w,tf.constant(np.asarray(relationMatrix),tf.float32))
        return tf.math.multiply(w,tf.transpose(tf.constant(np.asarray(relationMatrix),tf.float32)))
```

but then is crazy, if i use the first multilpy i have the following error :

> ```
> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 795 and 2 for 'training_63/Adam/Mul_17' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [795,2],
> ```
>
> [2,795].

if i use the second multiply

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 795 for
>   'training_64/Adam/Mul_6' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [2,795],
>   [795,2].

I cant understand whereis the error. Thank you in advance

Comment: tf.math.multiply(x,y) does element-wise multiplication between x and y. So for example, if x has dimensions [3,5] , y should also have [3,5] as dimensions. Check dimensions of 'w' and 'relationMatrix' before multiplying then and then try to convert accordingly.

Comment: Hi timedacorn, thank you for your answer, i checked the dimension of w, but that's the problem, that dimension change according to the matrix that i multiply with. I really dont understand where is the error.

Comment: making other experiments i just realized that the constraint function prova, is called twice, and everytime has a different shape.

Tensor("training_3/Adam/sub_4:0", shape=(2, 795), dtype=float32)
Tensor("training_3/Adam/sub_10:0", shape=(795, 2), dtype=float32)